# Output range for switch mode regulator

Tags: voltage, dc, variable

I'm using LM2576 regulator for having variable DC voltage. The output of the regulator specified in the datasheet is 1.23v to 37v. I need voltage to vary between 0v to 10v. I found that using a charge pump circuit a negative voltage of -1.23v can be produced and this compensates for 1.23v. Is there any other method?

Comment: Could you provide some additional info like why do you need the variable DC voltage and why is exactly this regulator chosen?

Comment: How much current do you need to be able to put out? What is your input voltage?

Comment: @lalamer I'm using this to control the brightness of light.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel as my aim is to control the brightness of light, 1A current is sufficient. LM2576 is capable of providing 3A current output.

Answer (score 1):

> I need voltage to vary between 0v to 10v

The problem faced with conventional adjustable voltage regulators is that they cannot simply produce output voltages lower than their internal reference voltage.

This is because the feedback pin compares the output voltage (potted down via resistors in a lot of cases) to that voltage reference and sets the operating output voltage level accordingly.

However, there are techniques that "falsely" raise the voltage fed-back that can convince the internal workings of the regulator to output a voltage lower than Vref and, in some cases, a voltage close to zero volts.

You could, with appropriate bias resistors, "add" 1.23V (Vref) to the fed-back voltage - this would naturally force the output to be zero volts. You could do it more accurately using an op-amp but care must be taken to avoid the op-amp causing extra phase shift in the feedback path because this could turn the regulator into an oscillator.

Comment: Thank you Andy.
Is there any other way to have a variable linear voltage control other than using adjustable voltage regulators?

Comment: Current-referenced regs (LT308x) can adjust down to 0 provided there's a load there that can use up the regulator's quiescent current.

Comment: @Zoozoo the words "variable" and "adjustable" are difficult to seperate. A totally different method is to use a DC amplifier and a variable voltage control input. The output of the amp has to be able to supply the load current and, conceivably, you could use a class D amplifier to make a pseudo synchrounous buck output.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel OK you got me there - I'll adjust my words LOL

Comment: @Andy aka can you please explain "add 1.23V(Vref)".

Comment: 1.23 volts is the internal voltage reference of the device and the voltage at which the FB input settles at when regulating. So, if you take your feedback signal and add 1.23 volts to it (various methods described in my answer) then your real output has to be 0V.